# Change UIAlertController Background Tint

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

Yes, I know. You can't change the appearance of a `UIAlertController`. I don't want to change the background of the `UIAlertController` itself, I want to change the tint of the view's background. You know how it's like a transparent black color? I want to change that color to clear. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

For swift 3 `UIAlertController` change background color.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "validate",message: "Check the process", preferredStyle: .alert)
let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(dismissAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:  nil)
// change the background color
let subview = (alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView
subview.layer.cornerRadius = 1
subview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (195/255.0), green: (68/255.0), blue: (122/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background colour as follows:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TITLE", message: "My message", preferredStyle: .alert)
if let subview = alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first {
    subview.backgroundColor = .red
}
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: This code makes a lot of assumptions about the private subview structure of a `UIAlertController`. It may work now. It may break in a future iOS update. Beware.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the transparent background color. That does not belong to part of `UIAlertController` variable that you can control.

You will have to fix it by presenting a new view controller with a transparent background and a faked alert-controller-like UI element.

To further approve you does not have control for the alert controller, create another view with frame origin on 0,0 and then add to your alert controller's view. It will show on the top left corner of your pop up window, not the window of your window

Comment: Sadly the only response that is answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
[alert.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Try changing whiteColor to whatever colour u wish.
To fix the corner extra color, add corner radius and run.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can create CustomAlertController, set your color in method `viewWillAppear` and show this controller instead of default `UIAlertController`. It's bad but working solution.

```
final class CustomAlertController: UIAlertController {
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        view.superview?.backgroundColor = yourColor
    }
}
```